# Merging two large data sets together

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Here are my two data frames, both have the same amount of rows which are 70492, I would like to merge them together,

This will not merge my data frames together

```
final <- merge(DF1,DF2)
```

The error i get is

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.1 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In merge.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y), ...) :
  Reached total allocation of 1535Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Sample of the data:

```
> Df1                       

  DaysInHospital    

1      0.7083160
2      0.7855017
3      1.4028831
4      0.5711540 
5      0.7084526
6      0.7035213

> DF2 

   MemberID ClaimsTruncated
1 20820036               0
2 14625274               1
3 99227820               0
4 74486714               0
5 92341995               0
6  7127539               0
```

Comment: If they have the same number of rows is it really a merge you want to do.  Perhaps `cbind(df1, df2)`?

Comment: If not this may be a job for an sql handling package.

Comment: data.table package with properly set keys is supposed to be more memory efficient as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have some column in common to merge on.  From what you desribed, with the same number of rows it's just...

```
final <- cbind(df1, df2)
```